# DaVinci Resolve: How to hide the timeline in the Deliver page

Tags: davinci-resolve

I'm using DaVinci Resolve 17 and on the Deliver page, the timeline panel takes up half the screen vertically (because I have a small monitor). It doesn't seem to be possible to shrink it with the cursor, so I'd like to hide it. But I can't find an option to do so in the View or Workspace menus. Is there some not-very-obvious way to hide it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t.  In Resolve, all of the main panels you can hide or un-hide are listed in tabs across the top of the screen.  So, you can hide the clips view for example, but not the timeline.

There are some sub-panels on the color page that expand and collapse by other means, but for the most part Resolve’s layout is less flexible than many NLE’s, but this is by design.  If your monitor meets Resolve’s minimum resolution specs and you still feel encumbered, you should submit a feature request or bug report to Blackmagic.  They are typically more receptive to user feedback than other NLE developers.

Most of the panels also have a button to toggle whether they occupy the full screen height. The Render Settings and Render Queue panels both support this on the Deliver page.  The buttons are directly adjacent to each tab, respectively.

Comment: Personally, I don’t think hiding it would be a good idea, even if you could, because there’s a high chance of outputting more or less than you intend.